# lexicographic order, hasse diagram problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let S1={7,8,9} and S2={2,3,4,6}. Let R1 be the "less than or equal to" relation on S1 and R2 be the "divides" relation on S2. Construct a Hasse diagram for the lexicographic order on S1 X S2.

Comment: What have you tried? To promote learning and discovery, it is prudent you share what approaches you took and what hurdles you faced.

Comment: So far I've crossed S1 and S2, giving me the set {(7,2),(7,3),(7,4),(7,6),(8,2),(8,3),(8,4),(8,6),(9,2),(9,3),(9,4),(9,6)} I'm not sure how a Hasse diagram can evolve from numbers such as these. Nor do I understand the lexicographic order quite yet.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write the two (S,R), nor how can I perform the relations for them when they're (<=) or (|). I'm trying to research L.O. right now online since the lecture today wasn't super clear.

Comment: I think I found R1 and R2, R1 = {(7,7), (7,8), (7,9), (8,8), (8,9), (9,9)}; R2 = {(2,2), (2,4), (2,6), (3,3), (3,6), (4,4), (6,6)}

Comment: My Hasse diagram looks kind of strange. I have 3 separate lines, each going straight up, the first column is (7,2)->(7,6), then (8,2)->(8,6), and (9,2)->(9,6).

Answer (score 0):

Lexicographic Order:
for $P=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,....,a_n\}$ and $Q=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_n\}$,
$(a_1,b_1)\le (a_2,b_2)$ in $ P X Q \iff$ (i) $a_1\le a_2$ in P or (ii) if $a_1=a_2, b_1≤b_2$

Here in this question,
$S_1 \times S_2= \{(7,2),(7,3),(7,4),(7,6),(8,2),(8,3),(8,4),(8,6),(9,2),(9,3),(9,4),(9,6)\}$
in $S_1$, $7≤8≤9$ and in $S_2$, $2≤4,2≤6$ and $3≤6$.

hence in $S_1 \times S_2$, $(7,2)≤(7,4),(7,2)≤(7,6)$ and $(7,2)$ is related to every element having $8$ and $9$ as first part if it.
Similarly for other elements.

Here is the Hasse diagram for lexicographic order on $S_1 \times S_2$

[image: Hasse diagram for lexicographic order on S1 X S2]